# Invalid Column Type Query

Tags: sql, oracle, exception

Stumped on trying to get this oracle db query to work properly. I am trying to extract all the records from the table that are between the dates that are selected on the front end.

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM COMPRATER_REQUESTS
    WHERE VendorName = ?
        AND EFFECTIVEDATE >= TO_DATE(?, 'yyyy/mm/dd')
        AND EFFECTIVEDATE <= TO_DATE(?, 'yyyy/mm/dd')
    )
WHERE ROWNUM <= 100
```

The parameters being passed to the placeholders are:

Parameters: [Walmart, Tue Jun 19 00:00:00 EDT 2018, Tue Oct 23 00:00:00 EDT 2018]

The error I keep getting back is:

> Error Message: An exception occurred while querying HVQ DB.
>   Exception stack trace: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type Query

Comment: Could you provide some sample data from your table?

Comment: what type is a date parameter? string or datetime? if date, so why you call to_Date, if string so why you are using a wrong format?

Comment: In the inner query, in the WHERE clause at the end you have `AND TO_DATE(...)`.  After the keyword `AND` you must have a logical condition, not an expression that evaluates to a date. What were you **trying** to do there? Perhaps have `EFFECTIVEDATE <=` ...?  Perhaps you edited your query, after initially you had a `BETWEEN ... AND ...` condition?

Comment: Sorry the second to_date should be <= before it. I must of removed it before I copied. But the issue is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input date strings don't match the format you're specifying in TO_DATE.

Parameters:

```
Walmart, 
Tue Jun 19 00:00:00 EDT 2018, 
Tue Oct 23 00:00:00 EDT 2018
```

From your query:

```
AND EFFECTIVEDATE >= TO_DATE(?, 'yyyy/mm/dd')
AND TO_DATE(?, 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

I think since you have a timezone in there, you need to use to_timestamp_tz function.

```
'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZD YYYY'
```

Comment: Well, if the time zone is important, then TO_DATE is wrong since Oracle dates do not support time zone. It should be TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ. But the error (the first error, anyway) that the OP encountered was at the parse stage already, the values were never even passed to the query (which only happens at runtime).

Comment: Yep. Should I delete this answer, or leave it as it addresses something else that is probably an issue with the query?